# J2EE :[Bad version number in .class file]

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee

I have deleted the earlier class and `.ear`-files, cleaned the workspace, compiled the code with JavaSE 1.6, set the system library to 1.6 then compiled and created the `.ear`. I am getting this error when I have installed the ear on server  and try to open with url:

```
 WebApp        E   [Servlet Error]-[Bad version number in .class file]: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader._defineClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:577)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.findClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:529)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:403)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.JSPExtensionClassLoader._loadClass(JSPExtensionClassLoader.java:103)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.JSPExtensionClassLoader.loadClass(JSPExtensionClassLoader.java:70)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.JSPExtensionClassLoader.loadClass(JSPExtensionClassLoader.java:52)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
```

Answer (score 1):

This error happens when your VM has another version (a lesser version) than the compiled class files. 
Could it be that your server still run with java 1.5?